# Pass properties from Jenkinsfile to POM.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

this is snippet of my Jenkinsfile in my project.

```
rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
rtMaven.resolver server: server, releaseRepo: env.RESOLVER_RELEASE_REPO, snapshotRepo: env.RESOLVER_SNAPSHOT_REPO
rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: env.DEPLOYER_RELEASE_REPO, snapshotRepo: env.DEPLOYER_SNAPSHOT_REPO
rtMaven.tool = mavenToolName
rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = false

Object runMavenBuildWithArgs(String... args) {
configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: mavenSettingsFileId, variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
    return rtMaven.run(
            pom: 'pom.xml',
            goals: '-U -s ' + env.MAVEN_SETTINGS + ' ' + args.join(' ')
    )
}
```

Here is simplified POM.xml properties I need to fill in.

```
<properties>
    <ant.artifactory.username>${artifactory.username}</ant.artifactory.username>
    <ant.artifactory.password>${artifactory.password}</ant.artifactory.password>
</properties>
```

Can I pass some arguments from Jenkinsfile to the pom.xml just before I call rtMaven.run() method? I need to fill in some properties inside pom.xml. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the args like below to the run commands.

```
-Dant.artifactory.username=XXXXXX -Dant.artifactory.password=YYYYY
```